# How to make multi-word argumet?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I make multi-word argumet. For example a reason for bans or mutes.If I use args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5]... so it's still limited and if nothing is written there, it will write "undefined". So if you knew how to do it, I would be very happy for the answer. :)

```
const { ReactionCollector } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "Dočasně zabanuje člena.",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, chalk, ms){
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1}).then(messages =>{
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });

        const channelId = client.channels.cache.get('802649418087530537');
        const author = message.author;
        const userName = message.mentions.users.first();
        
        if(!message.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")){
            message.reply('Nemáš potřebné permisse!')
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            });
            return;
        } else if(!args[1]){
            message.reply('!ban <člen> <délka> (<důvod>)')
            .then(msg => {
                msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
            });
            console.log(chalk.red('[ERROR] Missing args[1]'));
            return;
        }
        if(userName){
            const userId = message.guild.members.cache.get(userName.id);
            const botId = '799652033509457940';
            userId.ban();
            
            const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#a81919')
            .setTitle('Ban')
            .addFields(
                {name:'Člen:', value:`${userId}`},
                {name:'Udělil:', value:`${author}`},
                {name:'Délka:', value:`${ms(ms(args[1]))}`},
                {name:'Důvod:', value:`${args[2]}`},
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            channelId.send(banEmbed)

            setTimeout(function () {
                message.guild.members.unban(userId);

                const unbanEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#25a819')
            .setTitle('Unban')
            .addFields(
                {name:'Člen:', value:`${userId}`},
                {name:'Udělil:', value:`<@${botId}>`},
                {name:'Důvod:', value:`Ban vypršel.`},
            )
            .setTimestamp()
            channelId.send(unbanEmbed)
            }, ms(args[1]));

            console.log(chalk.green(`[INFO] /ban/ ${userId.user.username}, ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`));
        }else{
            message.channel.send('Nemůžeš zabanovat tohoto člena');
            console.log(chalk.red(`[ERROR] /ban/ Can not find target`));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `.shift()`, so you can `args.shift()` and then it will remove the first element in the array, then you can just join each word with a space like `args.join(" ");`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have defined `args` correctly. Then you can simply use

```js
args.join(" ");
```

to seperate each word with spaces.